# what is mysql max_allowed_packet? What is the max limit of rows for insertion data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to find maximum number of data user can enter into the mysql table using insert query?

is it depend on the `max_allowed_packet`?

If yes, can we update it? and what is the max value to set it?

If no, is it depend on some other constants of mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, the `INSERT` query should fit into one packet.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet):

> The protocol limit for `max_allowed_packet` is `1GB`. The value should be a multiple of `1024`; nonmultiples are rounded down to the nearest multiple.

To set it, use:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```